# Missing 'Android tests ' in Run Debug Configurations:add new configuration

Tags: android, android-studio, junit, android-testing

I was learning uiautomator and write some robots ,and I define my AndroidJUnitRunner in gradle:

```
testInstrumentationRunner "com.migou.robot.MigouJUnitRunner"
```

but get this error:

> Test running failed: Unable to find instrumentation info for: ComponentInfo{com.uiautomator.zyoung.uiautomatordemo.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner}

So I need to Specific instrumentation runner,but I can't add Android tests
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1aC1.png)